# Line Breaks in Entourage Emails

Tags: email, html, entourage

I have an entoruage client that when it receives HTMl emails, it completely ignores any line breaks in teh HTML, text just shows up all together. These mails look fine in Outlook and in webmail, just entourage. How can I get it to recognise these line breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Entourage still does not support [`format=flowed`](http://joeclark.org/ffaq.html), like in:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes
```

Maybe the HTML mails you get (erroneously) rely on that? We would have to see some e-mail headers and a bit of the content to ensure that's the reason though.

Maybe you can write some script to fix it, just like an issue with ActiveSync, for which you can [Use AppleScript to read ActiveSync Sent Items in Entourage](http://blog.entourage.mvps.org/2008/08/use_applescript_to_read_activesync_sent_items_in_entourage.html). But then we'd still need to see some detailed information.

<sup>(Shameless Mail.app plug, incase you're on 10.5 or later: Mail works *great* with Time Machine. You can even restore single messages from accounts that you have already deleted altogether. Just first activate Mail and then enter Time Machine. Bye bye Entourage...)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It actually sounds like it is doing the right thing here. In HTML, a plain old linebreak character has no meaning. To do a linebreak in html, you need to use a `<br />` tag, or enclose your text in `<p></p>` tags.

Comment: While it's doing the right thing, linebreaks should be converted into <br/> anyway. Preferably in the client!

Comment: The client of the **sender**, more importantly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant - sorry for being unclear :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML < br /> or < p>< /p> (good for HTML 4 transitional)

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem with Entourage. Using `"<br>"` instead of `"<br/>"` solved the problem.